# IF ELSE for the conditions of join?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server.

I have a table `item_table` like this:

```
item   age
--------------    
1      1 
1      6 
2      2
```

I have the other table `price_table` like this:

```
item    pricetype    price
--------------------------    
1       O             5
1       P             6
1       V             7
2       O             8
2       P             9
2       V             10
```

So, I want to inner join above two tables.

```
select *
from item_table i
inner join price_table p
on ...
```

There are some conditions about the `on`:

1. if **the average of age** of an item is bigger than `3`, then I do: `inner join price_table on pricetype = 'O' or pricetype = 'P'`
2. If not, then I do: `inner join price_table on pricetype = 'O' or pricetype = 'P' or pricetype = 'V'`

So there are conditions for `on` conditions.

**How can I write the select query?**

**Edit:**
I changed the condition to be **average of age**, instead of `type`

Comment: Do you want the join to return multiple rows for each row in your table?

Comment: You can use a case statement, or a derived query. Are you able to revise your data model though? Query performance will always be greater if your joins are simpler. Sometimes it's worth it even if you have some data redundancies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
select i.item, i.type, p.pricetype, p.price
from item_table i
inner join price_table p on i.item = p.item 
    and (i.type = 1 and p.pricetype in ('O', 'P'))
        or (i.type = 2 and p.pricetype in ('O', 'P', 'V'))
```

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f6957/2)

**Output:**

```
| ITEM | TYPE | PRICETYPE | PRICE |
-----------------------------------
|    1 |    1 |         O |     5 |
|    1 |    1 |         P |     6 |
|    2 |    2 |         O |     5 |
|    2 |    2 |         P |     6 |
|    2 |    2 |         V |     7 |
|    2 |    2 |         O |     8 |
|    2 |    2 |         P |     9 |
|    2 |    2 |         V |    10 |
```

Comment: @Beth Thanks, got interrupted mid-answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would put it in the `where` clause, myself, like:

```
select *
from item_table i
inner join price_table p on 
i.item = p.item
where
(pricetype in ('O', 'P'))
    or (type = 2 and pricetype in ('V'))
```

Comment: What is the advantage of doing it that way ?

Comment: For a inner join the `on` clause is compiled in to the `where` clause when run (Both methods are fine, this is just a fun fact)

Comment: @iDevlop for inner joins, the advantages are just cosmetic.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to have a table that maps between the two, um, types of types:

```
itemtype    pricetype
---------------------
1           O
1           P
2           O
2           P
2           V
```

Then you can inner join this table to the other two.